# SSIS Cannot convert between unicode and non unicode...but it's not true, how come?

Tags: unicode, ssis, oledb, dataflowtask

I have a simple DTSX that takes in some data, and write it to a SQL server DB, on this DTSX execution it throws me some errors on some fields:

```
[OLE DB Destination [29]] Error: Column "mobile" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.
```

But as you can see from the OLEDB DESTINATION COLUMNS MAPPING that's not true...how come?

[image]

Comment: First of all, what does your data model say? Is mobile from type varchar or nvarchar? Furthermore, did you change the OLE DB Source at one point or the other? SSIS behaves bitchy if you create a source which contains one type (varchar or nvarchar) and which is then modified in the query or in the advanced settings in order to use the other type instead. So basically - if the data model is correct - the best approach is to remove the OLE DB Source and recreate it afterwards with the correct type in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this not a long time ago. In the connection manager I had 'Unicode' checked. After I found out it wasn't unicode, I unchecked it, but the OLE DB input in the Data flow task didn't update and I had to delete the input and create it again.

Comment: I do not see what you are talking about. Could you provide a picture?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this issue by converting the data to varchar(max) while selecting from source table.